# Angular 1.5+ cannot dynamically create a component with '&' binding

Tags: angularjs

I am banging my head against a wall trying to dynamically build a component and insert into DOM. Everything works **except** for if my component has a '&' binding.

let's say component 'my-cmp' has the following bindings

```
bindings : {
   myBinding: '@',
   myFn:'&'
}
```

......... so now I dynamically create the component

```
let newScope = $rootScope.$new();
element = angular.element('<my-cmp my-binding="{{test}}"></my-cmp>');
 newScope.test = 'this works';
 element = $compile(element)(newScope);
```

this works great, no problem. *( I also have no problem with '<' bindings )*

But as soon as I try to add a '&' binding function, it breaks trying to compile.

```
let newScope = $rootScope.$new();
element = angular.element('<my-cmp my-fn="{{myFunction}}" my-binding="{{test}}"></my-cmp>');
newScope.test = 'this works';
newScope.myFunction = function(){
    return 'no workie';
}
 element = $compile(element)(newScope);
```

The error I get is: 
*Uncaught Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{myFunction}}] starting at [{myFunction}}].*

I know I obviously need to parse the '&' binding differently but I don't know how. Hopefully someone can help !
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the braces from your html?

Comment: that was it. you're a freakin' genius. thank you. my understanding of how that was parsed was obviously wrong:)